# Out of memory Unity flash

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine

Hi I have finished a game on unity but i need it to build it for flash and each time i try i get this error after the export.

```
Fatal Error : Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/set length()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/sbrk()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/malloc()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN21UnityDefaultAllocatorI17LowLevelAllocatorE8AllocateEji()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN13MemoryManager8AllocateEji10MemLabelIdiPKci()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_Z15malloc_internalji10MemLabelIdiPKci()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN9Texture2D8TransferI18StreamedBinaryReadILb0EEEEvRT_()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN9Texture2D23VirtualRedirectTransferER18StreamedBinaryReadILb0EE()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN14SerializedFile10ReadObjectEli18ObjectCreationModebPP8TypeTreePbPP6Object()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN17PersistentManager26LoadFileCompletelyThreadedERKSsPlS2_ibP12LoadProgress()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN21PreloadLevelOperation7PerformEv()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/_ZN14PreloadManager26UpdatePreloadingSingleStepEb()
    at com.unity::UnityNative$/NativeExt_LoadFirstLevel()
    at com.unity::UnityContentInternal/loadFirstLevel()
    at com.unity::UnityContent/onFrameInitStep()
```

Do any one knows how can i find where am i eating all the memory?

Comment: Maybe this thread is helpful: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/117164-Fatal-Error-null

Comment: yes thank you. I have read it, before i was just getting Fatal Error : null and in that thread i see how to get more info about the error

Comment: for any one with same problem. I solve it by deleting all textures and build, then add one by one and build until i got the error and found witch texture was the problem.